# UIView animateWithDuration not changing the frame of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to implement a drop down view which will move down when the user press the button and will be risen above again once the user press the same button. I am using following code for this purpose:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
        self.dropdownView.frame =
        CGRectMake(self.dropdownView.frame.origin.x,
                   self.dropdownView.frame.origin.y+42,
                   self.dropdownView.frame.size.width,
                   self.dropdownView.frame.size.height);
    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
        NSLog(@"%@",self.dropdownView);
    }];
```

Here what I am trying is to move the origin 42 points down to create dropdown sort of animation. In case of moving up, I am using:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
        self.dropdownView.frame =
        CGRectMake(self.dropdownView.frame.origin.x,
                   self.dropdownView.frame.origin.y-42,
                   self.dropdownView.frame.size.width,
                   self.dropdownView.frame.size.height);
    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
    NSLog(@"%@",self.dropdownView);

    }];
```

However, if I check the log, the frame of the dropdown view is not updated. However, If I use the same code in another VC with different UI elements, this code is working perfectly fine. In both cases, I have created the dropdown view in storyboard. What is wrong with the code so that it isn't working?

**Edit**

When I logged the constraints before first animation, the log was:

```
Constraints: (
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb01797460 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fcb01481970](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017c0ac0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fcb01481970]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017c0b10 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x7fcb01481970(320)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017aa360 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIImageView:0x7fcb01481970(42)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017aa3b0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fcb017e8080](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017824e0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(3)-[UIButton:0x7fcb017e8080]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb01782530 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIButton:0x7fcb017e8080(79)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb0179fe70 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIButton:0x7fcb017e8080(36)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb0179fec0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(82)-[UIButton:0x7fcb01796ea0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb01776490 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(3)-[UIButton:0x7fcb01796ea0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017764e0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIButton:0x7fcb01796ea0(79)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017956b0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIButton:0x7fcb01796ea0(36)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb01795700 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(164)-[UIButton:0x7fcb01699f60](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb01795860 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(3)-[UIButton:0x7fcb01699f60]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017958b0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIButton:0x7fcb01699f60(79)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017aef40 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIButton:0x7fcb01699f60(36)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017aef90 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(242)-[UIButton:0x7fcb01667610](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017b44b0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(3)-[UIButton:0x7fcb01667610]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017b4500 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIButton:0x7fcb01667610(79)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017bbde0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIButton:0x7fcb01667610(36)]>")
```

and the log of constraints once the animation was completed was:

```
Constraints: (
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb01797460 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fcb01481970](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017c0ac0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fcb01481970]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017c0b10 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x7fcb01481970(320)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017aa360 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIImageView:0x7fcb01481970(42)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017aa3b0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fcb017e8080](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017824e0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(3)-[UIButton:0x7fcb017e8080]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb01782530 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIButton:0x7fcb017e8080(79)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb0179fe70 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIButton:0x7fcb017e8080(36)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb0179fec0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(82)-[UIButton:0x7fcb01796ea0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb01776490 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(3)-[UIButton:0x7fcb01796ea0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017764e0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIButton:0x7fcb01796ea0(79)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017956b0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIButton:0x7fcb01796ea0(36)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb01795700 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(164)-[UIButton:0x7fcb01699f60](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb01795860 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(3)-[UIButton:0x7fcb01699f60]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017958b0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIButton:0x7fcb01699f60(79)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017aef40 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIButton:0x7fcb01699f60(36)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017aef90 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(242)-[UIButton:0x7fcb01667610](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017b44b0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(3)-[UIButton:0x7fcb01667610]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb014a16b0 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017b4500 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIButton:0x7fcb01667610(79)]>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017bbde0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIButton:0x7fcb01667610(36)]>")
```

**Edit 2**

That is what I want to achieve:
This is the view before animation. Once I click the arrow button, the view should move down as shown
[image: This is the view before animation. Once I click the arrow button, the view should move down as shown]

Here, the Arrange meeting and Post concert are two buttons which are subview of my dropdownView. They are there, even before the animation but they are behind the brown view, so they were not being shown, once I pressed the arrow button, they moved down and become visible

[image: Here, the Arrange meeting and Post concert are two buttons which are subview of my dropdownView. They are there, even before the animation but they are behind the brown view, so they were not being shown, once I pressed the arrow button, they moved down and become visible]

Comment: what do the log messages say?

Comment: It displays the same frame values for the view which were before the start of animation

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: how do you know? you are not logging before the start of the animation; please log before and after the animation and please _show_ what the log messages say, don't just talk _about_ them

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, I am using auto layout. And I am using it in both VCs, but I have not used any constraints on this dropdownView.

Comment: **You** may not have added constraints but that's irrelevant. If you are using AutoLayout then you are using AutoLayout. If you don't define constraints on a view then at build time it adds constraints for you. You need to animate the constraints not the frame. You can see this by doing this... `NSLog(@"Constraints: %@", self.dropdownView.constraints);`

Comment: @matt here is my log before animation: 2014-11-10 21:39:32.601 ******[22430:1264081] <UIView: 0x7fe0138489f0; frame = (0 22; 320 42); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fe0114fb100>>
2014-11-10 21:39:32.893 ******[22430:1264081] <UIView: 0x7fe0138489f0; frame = (0 22; 320 42); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fe0114fb100>>

Comment: @AMI289 I checked for the BOOL finished, it was 1 overtime the block was called.

Comment: I removed that, because after a second thought, even if the animation hasn't finished, the frame should have been changed....

Comment: Please show the context in which this code runs. Is it running on a background thread? You can't change the interface on a background thread.

Comment: @MuhammadJahanzaib please can you show the output for `NSLog(@"Constraints: %@", self.dropdownView.constraints);`

Comment: @Fogmeister have a look, I have added them in the question after editing.

Comment: @MuhammadJahanzaib ok, I was right. The line `IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame` shows that constraints have been added to the view by Interface Builder. If you want to animate it you need to set up constraints yourself and use them to animate the frame. When you're using AutoLayout you **cannot** directly edit the frame of a view. It won't work. Ever.

Comment: @Fogmeister How should I do it? I mean in this case, which constraint should I update for animation?

Comment: @MuhammadJahanzaib Don't even try to animate the auto added constraints. You need to setup these constraints in such a way that you can then animate the view as you would like. There is not enough information in your question to answer this. Can you show a **before** and **after** screenshot of what you want the view to look like. i.e. where it animates to and from.

Comment: Adding an answer but you'll need to change it for your own custom case...

Comment: I answered a similar question in that a view needed to be animated, though with auto-layout you no longer change the frame, rather animate the constraint values. Please see this answer which should be able to help you with your current requirements. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26635410/2507277

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are using AutoLayout you cannot update the `frame` or `center` of an app directly.

It just won't work. The constraints defining the frame will override any change you make and it will stay exactly where it is.

For your animation you need to set up constraints something like this...

[image]

You might want to set left space and right space instead of fixed width etc...

The top constraint needs to then be stored in a property...

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint;
```

It is this constraint that we can then change to animate the frame of the view. The only part of `NSLayoutConstraint` that is writable is the `constant` property. (Ironic)

Anyway, your animation code will be something like this...

```
self.topConstraint.constant += 42;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                 animations:^{
                     [self.view setNeedsLayout];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     NSLog(@"%@",self.dropdownView);
                 }];
```

Comment: help me to fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149922/setting-and-accessing-value-in-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-data

Comment: Hey i use above solution and works fine for me. i am requesting you to help in link question. i am stuck in it.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got it right by using the help from @Fogmeister along with utilising my original code. Using the code

```
self.topConstraint.constant += 42;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
             animations:^{
                 [self.view setNeedsLayout];
             }
             completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 NSLog(@"%@",self.dropdownView);
             }];
```

the frame of the view was being updated but it wasn't with the animation (a dropdown like stuff), so I utilised this with my original code (which was causing the animation, but at the end of animation, the view went back to its initial position) to get the desired results. My final code is:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                     animations:^{
                         self.topMarginConstraint.constant += 42;
                         [self.dropdownView setNeedsLayout];

                         self.dropdownView.frame =
                         CGRectMake(self.dropdownView.frame.origin.x,
                                    self.dropdownView.frame.origin.y+42,
                                    self.dropdownView.frame.size.width,
                                    self.dropdownView.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         NSLog(@"%@",self.dropdownView);
                     }];
```

Comment: You don't need to set the frame here. It is entirely redundant. You can just use the code I put into my answer and it will still work.