# UIView is not moving up when keyboard shown AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

My UIView is not moving up when keyboard shown and disappear when keyboard is hidden as well.

This coding is in ViewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

and this coding is for the rest.

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    [self animateTextField:TRUE];
}

- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)note
{
    [self animateTextField:FALSE];
}

-(void)animateTextField :(BOOL)up
{
    const int movementDistance = -130; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 1.0; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? movementDistance : - movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"animateTextField" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    _buttonsView.frame = CGRectOffset(_buttonsView.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: are you using auto layout? you cannot change directly the frame or center if the auto-layout is ON

Comment: @0yeoj yap, I'm using autolayout thus any solution then, pls?

Comment: @0yeoj can u post complete answer?

Comment: there is no relation been auto layout and your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With auto-layout you animate the constraint constant, though you don't change the CGRect frames. That was the old way.

Please see this link that I answered a similar question that they were having issues animating the movement of a UIView

[Animate UIView with layoutConstraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26635410/2507277)

This should help, though feel free to let me know if you need anything clarified.

Comment: can u post complete answer to more clarify?

Comment: @ppshein of course, though if you could tell me first, do you have the constraints added to the UIView? You will need to do this first, then CTRL drag one of the constraints concerning the distance of the view to the top or bottom of the screen.

Comment: It's working now and got new lesson from your answer. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this suits your implementation:

```
-(void)animateTextField :(BOOL)up
{
    const int movementDistance = -130; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 1.0; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (moveUp ? movementDistance : - movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"animateTextField" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    _buttonsView.frame = CGRectOffset(_buttonsView.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [_buttonsView setNeedsLayout];
}
```

**Edit**

I tried your code and calling `setNeedsLayout` did the work..

Answer (score 0):

use just below code you don't need to call it from any where

```
#pragma mark - move view up when keyboard is displayed


- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: NO];
}

- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
    const int movementDistance = 80; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    contentView.frame = CGRectOffset( contentView.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: ViewDidLoad

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil]; DELETE THIS CODE

Comment: did u click on uitextfiled

Comment: Can you check AutoLayout and run it again?