# Change TableView height When Tapped(using autolayout in xib)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xib

My ViewController looks like this when initially loaded:

[image: initially]

When show button is tapped it must change like this:
[image: When ShowButton tapped]

my code is:

```
- (IBAction)show:(id)sender {
 [self change];
 [tableView reloadData];
}
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender { 
 [self change];
 [tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)change{
  //assigning initial bounds to frame-1
  CGRect frame1=CGRectMake(0, _pastProcessTV.frame.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.pastProcessTV.bounds.size.height); 
  //assigning new bounds to frame-2
  CGRect frame2=CGRectMake(0, **CGFloat y**,self.view.bounds.size.width,***CGFloat height***);

   if (_showFullButton.isTouchInside) {
          tableView.frame = frame2;
    }
   else{
          tableview.frame = frame1;
   }
}
```

I tried different ways. it is not working.can anyone help me in giving Y-coordinate and width

Comment: Are you using autolayout in this?

Comment: yes i am using auto-layout

Comment: check the http://stackoverflow.com/a/35746197/2963912

Comment: @techloverr: This link belongs to this page only

Comment: @uday.m Not sure if you ever got this sorted, though if not, you need to change the constraints, not the frame of the tableView. Changing the frame is the old way before autolayout. Please see an answer I posted about someone's question for animating a UIView, though the principles are exactly the same here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26635410/2507277

Answer (score 1):

As you are using autolayout you have to take outlet of topconstraint of the tableview and when you want to expand it set its value to 0

So it will work as expected

if you are using iOS 7

`[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` is compulsary

Comment: and call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` afterwards

Comment: @techloverr: initially between tableView and navigation bar there are some other outlets like image view and buttons. Can  you explain with some sample code

Comment: then take a topconstraint with layoutguide or superview

Comment: @techloverr: can u give that frame-1 and frame-2 constraints

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use auto layout, please try like this picture

[Make Layout Constraint Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItIUX.png)

And try this code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    CGFloat oldtableViewTopValue;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tableViewTopLC;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    oldtableViewTopValue = _tableViewTopLC.constant;
}

- (IBAction)showBtnAction:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{

        _tableViewTopLC.constant = (_tableViewTopLC.constant==oldtableViewTopValue ? 0 : oldtableViewTopValue);

        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
@end
```

Answer (score -1):

Please turn off autolayout from Storyboard

[image]